# Is there a universally accepted value for no value?

Tags: default

I've seen N/A (always caps) used most often but I don't know if there is a standard.  My data will be seen on Google so I would like to use the most recognized value.

Comment: Are you asking for information to display to users or are you asking how to store the absense of a value in your code?

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on what you are trying to tell the user when there is no value.

For example, does no value mean that the data isn't available yet, but will be later? Or is the data point not applicable to the current record?

I would choose a value that imparts the most information.

Answer (score 3):

N/A means "Not Available" or "Not Applicable". I guess it's the most universally accepted term. But it really depends on the context if that's the best term.

Answer (score 2):

'null' is a common term I've seen quite often, especially when it involves programming.

Comment: May not be pretty but he didn't ask what is the most pleasant value, just the most common.

Comment: No, he asked for the most recognized value. My guess is that non-geeks don't recognize "null" very well. But it all depends on how you interpret the question. A compiler would of course recognize null better than n/a. (But compilers don't use google very often.)

Comment: Very Bad Answer if you are talking about a GUI form/something that any user would see.  Even a programmer seeing it would think "Man, that's some bad code to allow Null to just print like that!".  In code, however, it's the perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

N/A means Not Available.  "None" can work as well.

Also you really shouldn't rate someone down unless you know what you are talking about.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N/A

(Or just google N/A for 100 other references)

Comment: N/A means Not Applicable, not Not Availabe.

Comment: Actually it means Not Applicable

Comment: I thought about mentioning that--I've seen it used interchangeably as both, but Not applicable wasn't really, umm, applicable to his problem.

Comment: I don't think its one or the other, depends on the context

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I believe that N/A means [Not Applicable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N/A) and is often used when filling out forms.

I don't think there is a generally accepted standard for no value.  It depends on the problem domain.

For instance, null is common in the database and programming language arena.

In other cases, you might use "No value", "Empty", or "Blank".

Comment: As Wikipedia says, it can also mean "Not Available" (well known from ICQ).

Answer (score 0):

N/A is used for when there can't be a value, as the field/property does not apply in the context of the data item.

Usually, when the field/property applies in the context of the data item, but it does not have a value, people either leave it blank. (Or put (empty), though that's certainly less often)

Answer (score 0):

N/A also means Not Available or Not Applicable, so it is not a good idea. NULL is only used in databases, so regular users would not understand that. Best idea is to leave field blank or use a dash: -

It is also a good idea to mark the space where value should be shown with a different color. If you decide to leave it blank, you use a different background color. If you use - (or ---) you can then just use a different color for that character and have the same background. It all depends on your use case: where exactly do you need to display it.